# How all values hash to the same value with a given formula

Tags: hash-tables

When looking at hashing, and given the following question:

```
Given ASCII values: a = 97, b = 98, c = 99, d = 100, e = 101

Given keys: {e, ae, be, ce, de, abe, ace, ade, bae, cae, dae, bce, bde, cbe, dbe}

If we choose: h(k) = k mod 2^6 to map these keys to hash tables indexes, what do you notice?
```

The answer to this is that all of them hash to 37 but when I try this on a calculator they do not and I do not understand how to get 37. I think this has something to do with the low order bits reference in CLRS and the fact that it is not using a prime number but if I add for example:

`a + e = 97 + 101 = 198 % 64 = 6`

`b + e = 98 + 101 = 199 = 199 % 64 = 7`

When I look at the the binary for 6 and 7 they do not end up being the same and neither of the values above ends up resulting in 37.

Any help understanding this is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They want you to interpret a string of characters as a multi-byte integer.

So for example `abe` is intended to mean:

```
256^2*a + 256*b + e
```

Comment: Ok and so the lower order bits for this: 100101 which is 37, so where you have used the formula above how would that look for something longer than 3 characters?

Comment: Also how do you know that it is `256^2 * a` and then just `256 * b`?

Comment: @pac234 It's standard big-endian integer encoding.

Comment: I have read up on this as the book section doesnt actually mention anything about this (maybe it expects you just know it), I cannot find the formula though and how it would look for a longer sequence of characters.

Comment: I finally got what the book is asking\saying and maybe the maths equates to the same thing that you posted but its just worded differently? They ask you to calculate the radix value of the string, so `abe` = `(97 * 128) + (98 * 128) + 101 % 64 = 37`. Why is the last character in either method just added *as-is*?